# How can I check the touch gestures is enabled for the control or not?

Tags: c#, winforms, touch, gestures, gesture-recognition

In windows forms control, I have properly configured the touch gesture by using the **SetGestureConfig** method. It properly configured the touch gesture for the control. For some cases I need to check whether the control is properly enabled the particular touch gesture or not. I try to use the **GetGestureConfig** method, to check the particular gesture is enabled or not. But this method **always** **returns false value** alone.  And also I try to get the error message by using the **GetLastError() method**, but it is always returns the **value 0**. Please find the code below,

```
        int gestureConfigSize = Marshal.SizeOf(new GESTURECONFIG());
        GESTURECONFIG gc = new GESTURECONFIG();
        gc.dwID = 0;
        gc.dwWant = WindowMessages.GC_ALLGESTURES;
        gc.dwBlock = 0;
        if (SetGestureConfig(control.Handle, 0, 1, ref gc, gestureConfigSize))
            MessageBox.Show("Zoom gesture configured properly");

        GESTURECONFIG gc1 = new GESTURECONFIG();
        gc1.dwID = 0;
        gc1.dwWant = WindowMessages.GC_ALLGESTURES;
        gc1.dwBlock = 0;
        GESTURECONFIG[] gestures = new GESTURECONFIG[] { gc1 };

        bool value = GetGestureConfig(control.Handle, 0, 0, 1, gestures, gestureConfigSize);
        if (!value)
        {
            int errorValue = GetLastError();
        }
```

And please find the Dll import codes below,

```
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    static extern Int32 GetLastError();

    [DllImport("user32")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetGestureConfig(IntPtr hWnd, int dwReserved, int cIDs, [In] [Out] GESTURECONFIG[] pGestureConfig, int cbSize);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SetGestureConfig(IntPtr hWnd, int dwReserved, int cIDs, ref GESTURECONFIG pGestureConfig, int cbSize);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetGestureConfig(IntPtr hWnd, int dwReserved, int flags, int cIDs, [In] [Out] GESTURECONFIG[] pGestureConfig, int cbSize);
```

Please suggest how to check the touch gesture is enabled for the control or not by using the GetGestureConfig method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't `[DllImport]` GetLastError yourself in managed code, call `Marshal.GetLastError` (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adam_nathan/2003/04/25/getlasterror-and-managed-code/) for more details.
2. For this to work, you need to set the `SetLastError=true` flag in your `[DllImport]` to ensure that the error is captured.